# "а что если когда"?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте. Правильно ли говорить: "а что если когда"? И если так говорят, то в контексте ставится запятая только перед "а"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует устойчивое модальное выражение А ЧТО ЕСЛИ со значением, близким к  "может быть", например: " А что если самому пойти прямо «куда надо» и позвонить от них?" (Василий Аксенов). "Я подумал: а что если они оживут ― о чем станут говорить, что делать?"

Тогда предложение составлено верно: "Только представьте, а что если когда с полки падает кукла, то где-то и одна мечта разбивается на такое же количество осколков"?

Выражение А ЧТО ЕСЛИ относится с союзу КОГДА на правах частицы, модифицируя значение союза, запятая между ними не ставится, также не ставится запятая на стыке союзов "если когда", так как союз двойной: КОГДА...ТО.

Примечание

Выражение А ЧТО ЕСЛИ часто разделяется запятой, но мне это кажется неправильным, так как пауза там явно отсутствует: "А что, если она сейчас скажет: нет, это невозможно?"

Comment: Vera, вы сознательно ставите вопросительный знак вне кавычек? Вас тут предлагают править, а я не знаю, как к этому относиться. Если сознательно, то зачем?